# Size of the image in the toolbar

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, toolbar

I wanted to ask if there was a way to enlarge the image size in the toolbar, because the aspect tag is not recognized
enter code here `<ContentPage.ToolbarItems> <ToolbarItem IconImageSource="logo.JPG" x:Name="toolbar" /> </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>`

Comment: Hi Davide, could you show us the actual size, or how much do you want to enlarge it?

Answer (score 2):

We can not control the image size on the toolbaritem ,but as a workaround , `NavigationPage.TitleView` can be used to solve the problem .

Remove the `ContentPage.ToolbarItems` , set a `ImageButton` as `TitleView` , then adjust the image size .

```cs
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <StackLayout>
        <ImageButton Source="dog.png" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
    </StackLayout>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

Please check my test

Before (ToolbarItem)

[image]

After (TitleView)

[image]